# htaccess: rewrite URL to a file only if that file exists, but with regex captured groups

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a CMS that I've built myself in PHP (Codeigniter framework). I was thinking why every time PHP has to process all code just that to respond with a page. So instead I will create the complete HTML pages and serve them when a user asks for them.

That is why I need to rewrite an URL to a specific file only if that file exists. For this, I need to use regex captured groups because I want to build this for all files in that folder and subfolders.

For example, I want to put a bunch of HTML pages on %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/out and want to access them directly with rewrite rules.

For example, if the URL is like this:

```
htaaatps://www.dsaoidashd.com/services/development-of-desktop-applications
```

I want to look at the following location:

```
%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/out/services
```

for

```
development-of-desktop-applications.html
```

and if it exists, I want to return it to the client browser without continuing.

And of course, if I have yet more levels like this:

```
htaaatps://www.dsaoidashd.com/services/development/of-desktop-applications
```

then I need to check this location:

```
%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/out/services/development
```

for

```
of-desktop-applications.html
```

file and return it to the calling browser.

**I tried**

I know that I have to use RewriteCond to check if the file exists but how to pass it to the RewriteCond regex captured groups so I can check them based on the URL provided?

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/out/$1.html -f
RewriteRule ^.*$ /$1.html [L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `RewriteCond` is almost correct but you have to capture `$1` in a group in `RewriteRule` and also your target needs to be `out/$1.html`.

You can use this rewrite rule in your site root .htaccess:

```sh
RewriteEngine On

# To internally forward /dir/file to /out/dir/file.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/out/$1.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ out/$1.html [L]
```

Comment: It worked perfectly, now I need to figure out how to skip 404 pages because I have another code that is generating those HTMLs, but that is another story. Thank you!